# URL management / readable URLs in visual force

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, api-25

We are considering developing a new version of our website (where our customers can purchase and manage certain types of content) on the force.com platform. We have a business/usability requirement that urls needs to be readable and user friendly.

Can this be achieved when using visual force pages ? So far I've not come across anything trying to research this.

We would want to avoid any URL's like  http://example.com/services/​index.jsp?category=legal&id=patents, but have them as http://example.com/services/legal/patents

Comment: Are you building your website using Force.com sites?

Comment: To be honest, i'm not entirely sure of the difference (if any) between Force.com sits, and the sites you create out of your organisation. We have unlimited edition, and were planning to use the sites feature using custom portal authentication.

Comment: If you are building customer facing website, then you are probably using the Force.com sites feature.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do URL rewrites with Apex. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm for a good explanation of how to do this.

Comment: Note that your link is broken. I also have a related question here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/197254/38191 - please answer?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Force.com Site for this, you can customize the url to your hearts content as long as you register your Force.com domain for your organization. You can do so under Setup -> Develop -> Sites. Then setup a redirect from your domain name to this custom url.

Check out the [Sites FAQ](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Sites_FAQ) for more info.

Comment: I always get confused on most of the Salesforce lingo, but does the same go for sites developed using Site.com development tools? My org would like to have friendly URLs instead of www.company.com/ProductID=32408402482304 or whatever.

Comment: I understand your confusion. Site.com refers to a CMS system that you can build using (mostly) point and click. The pages you build can be for both internal users as well as external customers. I was referring to Force.com site pages which are basically bunch of visualforce pages built for external users. This article will help clarify your questions. http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Websites

Comment: This answer suggests using a HTTP redirect (301/302), but from the question I believe that this refers to rendering the page using a given URL (url rewriting) and not redirecting.

Comment: @EmmanuelF. - Site.com does support [alias URL redirects](http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/siteforce_redirects.htm) so you could redirect from www.company.com/product1 to www.company.com/genericProductPage?productId=32408402482304 and the user would only ever see www.comapny.com/product1.