# Accessing records via URL in Visualforce and sites

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I have a requirement to show the records to the user using my visualforce page in sites based on the url string.

Say for example my custom object name is position.

If a user enters :  https://siteprefix.sitedomain/MyPositions/1234
(or)
https://siteprefix.sitedomain/MyPositions/4567

MyPositions is my VF Page and it has necessary UI elements to show the details of the given record using the controller bound to it.

**Is it possible to access the position record with Name field value as  1234 or 4567  and show it based on the above given URL?**

as of now am doing like this

https://siteprefix.sitedomain/MyPositions?id=1234
(or)
https://siteprefix.sitedomain/MyPositions?id=4567

Comment: possible duplicate with : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122/url-management-readable-urls-in-visual-force

Comment: hi @Sdry thanks.. I had a look at it. Daniel has answered the same and in the URL he has mentioned they are asking to install CMSForce application which I dont want to do

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using the [Site.UrlRewriter Interface](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm).