# Is it possible to URL rewrite the VF page itself on Force.com Sites?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, force.com-sites, urlrewriter

Currently I am able to rewrite the link to mask the SFDC ID (not meant to be a real links) :

```
https://devenv.cs3.force.com/site/Unregistered?id=00XR12134152
```

to

```
https://devenv.cs3.force.com/site/Unregistered/John%20Smith
```

Where **Unregistered** = Visualforce page

However is there a way to URL rewrite the **VF page also** to say :

```
https://devenv.cs3.force.com/site/unreg/John%20Smith
```

Part of the VF Page:

```
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Page.CampaignMember_Reg, null, [id=CampaignMember.id])}">
                {!CampaignMember.Campaign_Name__c}
            </apex:outputLink>
         </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
```

**My Apex URL rewriter class :**

```
global with sharing class CMUrlRewriter implements Site.UrlRewriter {
//Variables to represent the user-friendly URLs for campaign member pages
String CAMPAIGNMEMBER_REG = 'CampaignMember_Reg/';
//Variables to represent my custom Visualforce pages that display campaign member information
String CAMPAIGNMEMBER_VISUALFORCE_REG = '/CampaignMember_Reg?id=';

global PageReference mapRequestUrl(PageReference myFriendlyUrl){
    String url = myFriendlyUrl.getUrl();

    if(url.startsWith(CAMPAIGNMEMBER_REG)){
        //Extract the name of the campaign member from the URL
        //For example: /CampaignMember_Reg/Ryan returns Ryan
        String cmName = url.substring(CAMPAIGNMEMBER_REG.length(), url.length());

        //Select the ID of the Campaign Member that matches the name from the URL
        CampaignMember cpm = [SELECT Id FROM CampaignMember WHERE Name__c =: cmName LIMIT 1];

        //Construct a new page reference in the form of the VF page
        return new PageReference(CAMPAIGNMEMBER_VISUALFORCE_REG + cpm.id);
    }

    //If the URL isn't in the form of a Campaign Member page, continue with the request
    return null;
}

global List<PageReference> generateUrlFor(List<PageReference> mySalesforceUrls){
    //A list of pages to return after all the links have been evaluated
    List<PageReference> myFriendlyUrls = new List<PageReference>();

    //A list of all the ids in the urls
    List<id> cpmIds = new List<id>();

    // loop through all the urls once, finding all the valid ids
    for(PageReference mySalesforceUrl : mySalesforceUrls){
        //Get the URL of the page
        String url = mySalesforceUrl.getUrl();

        if(url.startsWith(CAMPAIGNMEMBER_VISUALFORCE_REG)){
            //Extract the ID from the query parameter and store in a list for querying later in bulk.
            String id= url.substring(CAMPAIGNMEMBER_VISUALFORCE_REG.length(), url.length());
            cpmIds.add(id);
        }
    }

// Get all the account names in bulk
List <CampaignMember> cpms = [SELECT Name__c FROM CampaignMember WHERE Id IN :cpmIds];

Integer counter = 0;

// Go through all the urls again, so that the order of the urls in the list is maintained. 
for(PageReference mySalesforceUrl : mySalesforceUrls) {

   //Get the URL of the page
   String url = mySalesforceUrl.getUrl();

   if(url.startsWith(CAMPAIGNMEMBER_VISUALFORCE_REG)){
        myFriendlyUrls.add(new PageReference(CAMPAIGNMEMBER_REG + cpms.get(counter).Name__c));
        counter++;
   } else {
        //If this doesn't start like an Campaign Member page, don't do any transformations
        myFriendlyUrls.add(mySalesforceUrl);
   }
}
//Return the full list of pages
return myFriendlyUrls;
  }
}
```

so for this part of the code, I tried changing it to  :

```
if(url.startsWith(CAMPAIGNMEMBER_VISUALFORCE_REG)){
        myFriendlyUrls.add(new PageReference('Masked_VF_Page/' + cpms.get(counter).Name__c));
        counter++;
}
```

but I got an error saying "Sorry we cannot find any VF pages called 'Masked_VF_page/'"

Comment: Have you tried using `'/Masked_VF_Page/'` instead? I'll try to recreate what you have in a dev org later today.

Comment: I will still get     'Page Not Found: /Masked_VF_Page/John%20Smith'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a URL rewriting class on your site to accomplish this. Hard to write an example in this answer as it is pretty complicated, but this post explains it well: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm

After looking at your code in my org, I think all you need to do to have

`https://devenv.cs3.force.com/site/reg/John%20Smith` map to `https://devenv.cs3.force.com/site/CampaignMember_Reg?id=00XR12134152` is to modify the line:

`String CAMPAIGNMEMBER_REG = 'CampaignMember_Reg/';`

to be

`String CAMPAIGNMEMBER_REG = '/reg/';`

Note, be careful about using Name here because if it isn't unique, you'll have issues when it finds multiple with the same name.

Here's an example where my VF page is called "CampaignMember_Reg" and the rewrite is to reg.

[image: rewritten page]

Comment: No disrespect but my question can't be answered using a cookie-cutter answer like yours. I have gone through same damn link for days. Their example clearly allows u to mask the ?id=xxx portion to whatever you want. 

Their example is about "simple site consisting of 2 Visualforce pages: mycontact and myaccount" which they didnt mask at all.

I have tried url rewriting the VF pages at several places in their "Example URL Rewriting Apex Class" but I keep getting the error that it CANNOT FIND THE VF PAGE which starts to hint strongly that you can't simply rewrite the VF page to somthing else.

Comment: You aren't rewriting one VF page to another. You are implementing the Site.UrlRewriter interface and assigning that class to your site. Your VF pages won't need any masking themselves. Maybe post an example of what you've tried.

Comment: ok question has been updated to show what I have tried.

Comment: @compski I updated this answer

Comment: When changing the string to String CAMPAIGNMEMBER_REG = 'reg/'; or String CAMPAIGNMEMBER_REG = '/reg/'

I get the error that the "page is down for maintenance". So I guess the VF page can't be re-writed then.

Comment: No, it is definitely possible. I have a working example in my developer org. It may be an issue with permissions.